# problem while creating dynamic labels for chart js

Tags: javascript

I am creating dynamic labels for the chart js by supplying range of the month . It is working good if i selected start month and end month in ascending order but it is not working in the case where i selected start month = december and end month = march.

Here is my code ,

```
var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

var monthArr = [];

var monthn = ['December','March']; // here i give the lower and upper limit for the label 
for (var i = monthNames.indexOf(monthn[0]); i <= monthNames.indexOf(monthn[1]); i++) {
    monthArr.push(monthNames[i]);
}

return monthArr;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

var monthArr = [];
var monthn = ['December','March'];
if (monthNames.indexOf(monthn[1]) < monthNames.indexOf(monthn[0])) {
    monthNames.unshift(monthNames.splice(monthNames.indexOf(monthn[0]), 1)[0]);
    for (var i = monthNames.indexOf(monthn[0]); i <= diff; i++) {
        monthArr.push(monthNames[i]);
    }
} else {
    for (var i = monthNames.indexOf(monthn[0]); i <= monthNames.indexOf(monthn[1]); i++) {
        monthArr.push(monthNames[i]);
    }
}

return monthArr;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to validate the index between the two months

Here is an example with your code and a very small changes.

```js
    var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

    var monthArr = [];

var monthn = ['December','March']; // here i give the lower and upper limit for the label 

    // make sure that StartMonth is smaller then Endmonth
    var startMonth = monthNames.indexOf(monthn[0]) <= monthNames.indexOf(monthn[1]) ? monthNames.indexOf(monthn[0]) : monthNames.indexOf(monthn[1]);

    // make sure that EndMonth is bigger then StartMonth
    var endMonth = monthNames.indexOf(monthn[0]) <= monthNames.indexOf(monthn[1]) ? monthNames.indexOf(monthn[1]) : monthNames.indexOf(monthn[0]);

    for (var i = startMonth; i <= endMonth; i++) {
        monthArr.push(monthNames[i]);
    }

    // Add the missing months
    if (startMonth -1 >0)
     {
       for (var i = 0; i <= startMonth -1; i++) {
        monthArr.push(monthNames[i]);
        }
     }

    console.log(monthArr)
```

Comment: where is jan and feb ?

Comment: Did you not want to begin from March and end it to December ? otherwise you could always start from January. did i understand you wrong ?

Comment: Ok now i understod what you wanted, i made some changes it should work as you like now, have a look